# How to change properties in all Forms in VisualStudio Project?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

I have project with 50+ form. And I want to change icon in all form, that all forms have the same icon. How Can I do it?

Comment: You want to change or to set an icon for every form?

Comment: Yes. And I want to change some others properties in all windows. For example, properties "Cursor".

Comment: You can create a `Form` in your project and name it `BaseForm`. Then set properties like `Icon` and `Cursor` then in all other forms, you can inherit `BaseForm` instead of `Form`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Form` in your project and name it `BaseForm`. Then set properties like `Icon` for `BaseForm`. Then in all other forms, you can inherit `BaseForm` instead of `Form`.

This way, all forms which you didn't touch their `Icon` property will use the values which is set in `BaseForm`. So if you want a `Form` to have a different `Icon` than the `BaseForm`, it's enough to change the `Icon` property in that form explicitly.

You can also use this approach for other properties like `Cursor` which you mentioned in comments.

Comment: You can change it simply using a find/replace, find " : Form" and replace all with " : BaseForm" by look in current project or all open documents. Just pay attention to not replace the base class for `BaseForm` itself.

Comment: Thanks for answer!